# Awesome-WM keyboard shortcut double-tap

Tags: lua, configuration-files, awesome-wm

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut that acts differently on single vs double-tap. For example:

- Mod4+"s" start-player
- Mod4+"ss" stop-player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mod4+ss` is registered/handled as `Mod4+s`,`Mod4+s`. So, does something like the following count? The following function would be the callback function for you key. This function starts a timer the first time you press `Mod4+s`. If no second press follows in 0.1 seconds, then this counts as a single tap. Otherwise, the timer is stopped and a double tap is registered.

```
local double_tap_timer = nil
local function press()
    if double_tap_timer then
        double_tap_timer:stop()
        double_tap_timer = nil
        print("We got a double tap")
        return
    end

    double_tap_timer = gears.timer.start_new(0.1, function()
        double_tap_timer = nil
        print("We got a single tap")
        return false
    end)
end
```

(I only wrote the code, I didn't actually test this. Let's consider that as an exercise for the interested reader.)